# SAPUI5 Using XML-File as View with "data-sap-ui-resourceroots"?

Tags: xml, eclipse, view, sapui5

I'm doing the SAPUI5 Walkthrough and stuck at step 4. [(Walkthrough Step 4)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1409791afe4747319a3b23a1e2fc7064.html)

I'm working with Eclipse and don't know how to change this code-line so it works for my project and is going to find my view.

```
         data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.ui.demo.wt": "./"
     }'
```

I need to know what to insert for "sap.ui.demo.wt" when using an Eclipse project.

Thanks for any hints :)

EDIT:

Now I got a working page with a button which triggers a pop-up.

Folder structure:

```
SAPUI5_Test
 - WebContent
    - controller
       -> NewView.controller.js
    - view
       -> NewView.view.xml
    - index.html
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SAPUI5 Walkthrough</title>
    <script
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-preload="async"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "SAPUI5_Test": "./"
        }'>
    </script>
    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.xmlview({
                viewName: "SAPUI5_Test.view.NewView"
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

NewView.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="SAPUI5_Test.controller.NewView"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
<Button 
text="Say hello"
press="onShowHello"/>
</mvc:View>
```

NewView.controller.js

```
sap.ui.controller("SAPUI5_Test.controller.NewView", {
    onShowHello : function() {
        alert("Hello SAPUI5_Controller");
    }
});
```

So thanks for the help! And maybe this could help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SAPUI5 is searching for resources like views, controllers or other classes by their full names.

It is assuming that every namespace part is a folder and the class/view name is the filename. If its a view the filename has to be xxx.view.xml. if its a controller the filename has to be xxx.controller.js.

The root folder where it starts its search is by default the folder of the sap-ui-core.js.

You can change the root folder by defining a data-sap-ui-resourceroots mapping. Its a javascript object that maps a namespace to a path (relative to the index.html).

With the following bootstrap tag `company.myProject.view.View1` is searched for at `/resources/company/myProject/view/View1.view.xml`:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```

With this bootstrap tag `company.myProject.View1` is searched for at `/view/View1.view.xml`:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
      "company.myProject": "./" }'></script>
```

And with this bootstrap tag `company.myProject.View1` is searched for at `ddd/myProject/view/View1.view.xml`:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
      "company": "./ddd" }'></script>
```

Edit: Please beware that you have to use `"` inside of the map. `'` will not work.

---

Edit: Clarification of folder structure

I would recommend that you put everything in a project namespace. Use this folder structure:

```
WebContent
- controller
  - NewView.controller.js
- view
  - NewView.view.xml
- index.html
```

- Rename *View* folder to *view* (namespaces are camelCase by convention).
- Rename *newView.view.xml* to *NewView.view.xml* (Classes/Views are PascalCase by convention)
- Use `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "myproject": "./" }'`.
- Change your Controller name to *myproject.controller.NewView*: `Controller.extend("myproject.controller.NewView", {...});` or `sap.ui.controller("myproject.controller.NewView",{...});`.
- In the xmlview use `controllerName="myproject.controller.NewView"`.
- Instantiate the view with `sap.ui.xmlview({ viewName: "myproject.view.NewView"}).placeAt("content");`.

With that you don't have to add a mapping for every subfolder in your project.

Comment: Ok thanks :) So I created a view in MyProject -> WebContent 
Can you give me an example how to set the resourceroots for that?

Comment: The path you supply as resourceroot is relative to the index.html which is located inside the WebContent folder. So the WebContent folder is irrelevant for the mapping. Inside your WebContent folder you should find a myproject folder which contains your myproject.View1. Then this is the mapping to use: `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"myproject":"./myproject"}'`

Comment: Thanks schnoedel ! I think it worked.
Just to sum it up. My project structure looks like this now 

"MyProject -> WebContent -> View -> newView.view.xml".
"View" is a folder containing my view xml-file. 

I know added like you said schnoedel. 
`data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "View": "./View" }' `

and below
[...]
`sap.ui.xmlview({ viewName: "View.newView"}).placeAt("content");`
[...]

Made my day schnoedel ;)

Comment: Great! I would recommend to use a project namespace though. Added it to my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks :) I changed everything like you said. I just have one problem that I had before. When I enter a "controllerName" into my XML View it doesn't show my button anymore. Any ideas?

Controller:
`sap.ui.define([
               "sap/ui/mvc/Controller"
               ], function (Controller) {
      "use strict";
      return Controller.extend("SAPUI5_Test.controller.NewView", {
      });
}); `

XML:
`<mvc:View
   controllerName="SAPUI5_Test.controller.NewView"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
   <Button 
        text="Say hello"
        press="onShowHello"/>
</mvc:View>`

Comment: Ok I solved it. Little mistake by me :) I'm going to edit my post above so if someone got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution by @schnoedel didn't work for me until i changed `src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"` to `src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"`  next to installing openui5 in webapp/resources. It seems the location of index.html is only used as root when using a local installation. I debugged the resource root while using the remote variant and it failed with error message "cannot load [https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/view/App.view.xml"](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/view/App.view.xml%22).

Comment: Most probably the view couldn't be found because of the wrong folder structure. `webapp` should contain only application resources an not the entire framework. For more information, see _[Folder Structure: Where to Put Your Files](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/003f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a)_.