# Imports in JavaScript?

Tags: eclipse, import, sapui5

I found a tutorial for SAPUI5 with XML.
So I got now a index.html, a mainView.view.xml and a mainView.controller.js

In the controller I got a method for handling a button click.

```
sap.m.MessageToast.show("Hello");
```

But that it works I need to write "sap.m. [...]" everytime I want to call a method. Isn't there a way to import the sap.m lib so I can just write `MessageToast.show` ?

Comment: a `var MessageToast = sap.m.MessageToast;` should do the job

Comment: isn't there a more dynamic option? Because when I want to use another method from "sap.m" I also need to implement a variable for that, and so on... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current [sapui5 documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/f665d0de4dba405f9af4294de824b03b.html) propagates the *Asynchronous Module Definition* (AMD) pattern for your javascript classes.

There you have to import all the needed classes explicitly one by one. But afterwards you can use them without namespace: `MessageToast.show("Hello");`.

The advantage of the AMD pattern is that the needed resources can be loaded asynchronously from the server.

---

If you don't want to use AMD, RCs comment to your question is the way to go: `var MessageToast = sap.m.MessageToast;` or you could do something like `var m = sap.m; m.MessageToast.show("hello");` but i would not recommend that.

Comment: Ok I informed me about AMD now and going to use it :)

If somebody got the same issue maybe this
[Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721522/sapui5-using-xml-file-as-view-with-data-sap-ui-resourceroots) and this [Walktrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/f665d0de4dba405f9af4294de824b03b.html) may help. ;)