# SAPUI5 code from OpenSAP week 1 unit 2 not working

Tags: sapui5

i am following SAP UI5 course from OpenSAP, and in week 1 unit 2, when I do, what is given in exercise my code doesn't work.

Any help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   
    <script
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-preload="async"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"opensap.MyApp": "./"}'
        >
    </script>

    <script src="https://sap.github.io/openSAP-ui5-course/Validator.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.xmlview({viewName: "opensap.MyApp.view.App"}).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my view which is present in view folder

```
<mvc:View
displayBlock="true"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
xmlns="sap.m"
<Carousel>
    <pages>
        <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/GEO_Globe.jpg"/>
        <Image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/GEO_Globe.jpg"/>
    </pages>
</Carousel>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record why `"../"` worked out: It depends on how your project folder structure looks like. With `'{ "opensap.myapp": "../" }'`, you're [registering a module path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270607/5846045) to your app by saying "Whenever I'm using `"opensap.myapp."` as a prefix, start to search for the resource from the path `../` relative to where my current document is located (in our case, index.html)." thus resource**Root**.

- Best practice of how to structure your project folder can be found here: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/003f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a.html
- Here is another answer which explains the issue further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35722435/5846045

---

PS: You might encounter some cosmetic bugs if you keep using the theme `sap_bluecrystal` [due to its deprecation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/a87ca843bcee469f82a9072927a7dcdb.html) (since version 1.38). Better use `sap_belize` or `sap_belize_plus`, if your app is running on a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody who is suffering similar to me.

Instead of using

```
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
    "opensap.myapp": "./"
}'>
```

Use `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "opensap.myapp": "../"
    }'>`

After struggling a whole hour, I tried this and it worked. Whatever syntax given in docx file in the exercise is wrong. Or either that some feature is updated.