# When to use jQuery.sap.registerModulePath() with an example?

Tags: sapui5

I have tried reading the SAPUI5 documentation for the above but I am not able to clearly understand its usage. Also what is the difference between `sap.ui.localResources()` and `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath()` and when to use what?

If someone can explain with an easy example it will be really helpful. Also can we use `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath()` to load mockData?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you were using `resourceRoots` either in the [bootstrap config](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) or in the [app descriptor](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da), you've been using [`jQuery.sap.registerModulePath`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.registerModulePath) all the time as each key-value pair, defined in `resourceRoots`, is passed as arguments to that static method.

For example, you may have something like this in your index.html:

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"my.app": "./"}'
  ...
></script>
```

UI5 then registers the *namespace* (`"my.app"`) globally as a reference saying "Whenever that name is mentioned while resolving other module names, I should look for the target module in the *registered path*" which is `"./"` relative to the current `document.location.href` in our case.

The above code is the same as calling `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("my.app", "./")`<sup>[1]</sup> directly.

- Here, we can pass user-defined URL prefix. E.g.: `"../"` instead of `"./"` which is needed if the project has another *.html file in [one hierarchy level deeper such as *mockserver.html*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/003f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a)
- If we've a module in a deeper hierarchy, e.g. in `custom/control/somewhere/c3/chart/`, we can register another namespace: `"my.app.c3chart": "./custom/control/somewhere/c3/chart"` and then

  - Use it as a shortcut for example in the XMLView definition:
    `xmlns:c3="my.app.c3chart"` instead of
    `xmlns:c3="my.app.custom.control.somewhere.c3.chart"`.
  - Reduce maintenance costs by changing only the registered path when the module file changes its hierarchy level. The namespace `"my.app.c3chart"` can still be used everywhere.

[1]: As of 1.58, the API is deprecated. When registering namespaces manually, the API [`sap.ui.loader.config`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.loader/methods/sap.ui.loader.config) should be used:

```js
sap.ui.loader.config({
  paths: {
    "my/anotherApp": "https://example.com/somePath/anotherApp"
  }
});
```

---

> What is the difference between sap.ui.localResources() and jQuery.sap.registerModulePath()?

Here is the current [source code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/ad016b6faab3979f541f9ff8e6af81732e4b5618/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/Global.js#L430) of what [`sap.ui.localResources`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.localResources) actually does:

```js
sap.ui.localResources = function(sNamespace) {
  jQuery.sap.registerModulePath(sNamespace, "./" + sNamespace.replace(/\./g, "/"));
};
```

That's it. It calls `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath` right away with the dots in the namespace (if any) replaced with `"/"`.

- We can't pass any user-defined URL prefix
- The namespace is tightly coupled with the actual folder hierarchy and name.
- [SAP discourages](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7b390faab1140c087b8926571e942b7/latest/en-US/88681e71e3584497908a30767d28ac78.html) the usage of this API (for non-stand-alone apps).
- The API reference mentions that this API <s>will become obsolete.</s> [is deprecated](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/30350ed495deef394de381dc57bc416d43a50cf2)